# ASP.NET MVC 4 returns HttpStatusCodeResult "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-codes

I am doing some functionality change to a preexisting MVC 4 application. Whenever an exception is thrown, somehow the framework is capturing it and throwing an HttpStatusCodeResult instead of the error.

This is fine when I am doing remote debugging but when other users are using the application and testing it, they receive a return new HttpStatusCodeResult with "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

I deployed the code in debug mode, and I want to know how to turn this off so I can see any stack traces on the testing user's computer.

This is how the webconfig is set:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true" />
```

But I still get the dialog box thrown every time an exception occurs. I want to turn this off and get the actual stack-trace for the exception while this is in the test environment. This way I can debug why certain users are getting an "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" dialog message displayed and others are not.

Comment: So what is the question? Internal sever error means the resources are not accessible.

Comment: Custom errors are off, debug is on (both bad if you're wanting to use an error interceptor page in prod) and you've shown no code around the global asax' application_error handler.  How are we actually supposed to help you?

Comment: Whenever an exception is thrown, an internal server error dialog pops up. How do I see the stack trace instead on the screen.

Comment: You don't WANT to see stack trace on the screen! You should be logging it discretely AWAY from the user!

Comment: I know this. This is a testing environment, and this is not code I wrote. I am trying to debug the error.

Comment: I am a Novice with ASP.NET MVC 4, so the question is vague because I don't know enough about what is happening to know what code to show.

Comment: It's hard to say where exactly it is happening when the user submits. This code is very tightly coupled so there is a lot of different classes called and long chained method calls. Ajax is being used though. I am hoping to be able to get the stack-trace some how from the server shown on the screen.

Comment: Internal server error almost always means the controller method is throwing and exception. Use you browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response, which will include details of the error.